# Выполнение callback_data + web_app в InlineKeyboardButton telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Всех приветствую! Столкнулся с проблемой последовательного выполнения callback_data, затем web_app в InlineKeyboardButton. Как бы можно было это реализовать?

```
btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='Текст', web_app=webApp)
```

Соответственно после выполнения callback_data запускать web_app, но этого не происходит((
Как бы можно было это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, нужно открыть веб-страницу.

Откажитесь от использования **web_app**, замете его на **url**

```
btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Текст', callback_data='Текст', url='https://ru.stackoverflow.com')
```

Comment: Так-то оно работает, но мне это не подходит, поэтому обратился за помощью! Мне нужно, чтобы прям из телеграмма открывался сайт, не в браузере